# Cannot build vue3 vite app due to assigning read only property 'name'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I have laravel app that uses vite, vue3 and inertiajs.

I was able to build it before, however I cannot anymore with error being:

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function '(userOptions) => {
    const meta = {
      framework: "vite"
    };
    const rawPlugins = toArray(factory(use...<omitted>... }'
error during build:
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function '(userOptions) => {
    const meta = {
      framework: "vite"
    };
    const rawPlugins = toArray(factory(use...<omitted>... }'
    at normalizePlugins (file:///C:/laragon/www/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25984:25)
    at getInputOptions (file:///C:/laragon/www/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25971:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async rollupInternal (file:///C:/laragon/www/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25911:72)
    at async build (file:///C:/laragon/www/proj/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:46471:18)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///C:/laragon/www/proj/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:812:9)
```

`npm list`:

```
PS C:\laragon\www\proj> npm list
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
proj@ C:\laragon\www\proj
├── laravel-vite-plugin@0.7.3
├── lodash@4.17.21
├── postcss@8.4.24
├── prettier@2.8.8
├── sortablejs@1.15.0
├── sweetalert2@11.7.12
├── unplugin-vue-components@0.25.1
├── vite@4.3.9
├── vue@3.2.45
└── vuetify@3.0.6
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/vue3": "^1.0.0",
        "@mdi/font": "^7.1.96",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "eslint": "^8.42.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.14.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "prettier": "2.8.8",
        "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.25.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.41"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.0.0-beta.212",
        "@tiptap/vue-3": "^2.0.0-beta.212",
        "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
        "sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.7.12",
        "vuetify": "^3.0.6"
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? Should I provide more information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I removed `"unplugin-vue-components"` and everything works now.